# Android upload image to jsp page

Tags: android, jsp, java-server

i want to upload image from my android app to jsp server's page which process and save image into the server.But I get `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException` when i debug it.This is my code in jsp page.

```
String contentType = request.getContentType();
    //here we are checking the content type is not equal to Null and as well as the passed data from mulitpart/form-data is greater than or equal to 0
    if ((contentType != null) && (contentType.indexOf("multipart/form-data") >= 0)) {
                InputStream in = request.getPart("Image").getInputStream();

        //DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(request.getInputStream());
        //we are taking the length of Content type data
        int formDataLength = request.getContentLength();
        byte dataBytes[] = new byte[formDataLength];
        int byteRead = 0;
        int totalBytesRead = 0;
        //this loop converting the uploaded file into byte code
                    while (totalBytesRead < formDataLength) {
                            byteRead = in.read(dataBytes, totalBytesRead, formDataLength);
                            totalBytesRead += byteRead;
                    }

        String file = new String(dataBytes);
        //for saving the file name
        String saveFile = file.substring(file.indexOf("filename=\"") + 10);
        saveFile = saveFile.substring(0, saveFile.indexOf("\n"));
        saveFile = saveFile.substring(saveFile.lastIndexOf("\\") + 1,saveFile.indexOf("\""));
        int lastIndex = contentType.lastIndexOf("=");
        String boundary = contentType.substring(lastIndex + 1,contentType.length());
        int pos;
        //extracting the index of file 
        pos = file.indexOf("filename=\"");
        pos = file.indexOf("\n", pos) + 1;
        pos = file.indexOf("\n", pos) + 1;
        pos = file.indexOf("\n", pos) + 1;
        int boundaryLocation = file.indexOf(boundary, pos) - 4;
        int startPos = ((file.substring(0, pos)).getBytes()).length;
        int endPos = ((file.substring(0, boundaryLocation)).getBytes()).length;
        // creating a new file with the same name and writing the content in new file
        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(getServletContext().getRealPath("/")+"images/"+saveFile);
        fileOut.write(dataBytes, startPos, (endPos - startPos));
        fileOut.flush();
        fileOut.close();
```

how can i fix this?

---

Here's error log: 
`>Exception occurred in target VM:

java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: 
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:327)
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.threadio.ThreadInputStream.read(ThreadInputStream.java:87)
    at org.apache.jsp.upload_jsp._jspService(upload_jsp.java:64)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:403)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:492)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:378)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1539)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:98)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:174)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:725)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1019)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
<`
This log is visible when i debug to this row **byteRead = in.read(dataBytes, totalBytesRead, formDataLength);** in the second looping of **while (totalBytesRead < formDataLength)**

Comment: Why don't you use the library such as http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/ ?

Comment: sorry! my Reputations are not enough for me to post error log right now, i'll post it after

Comment: You have used `indexOf()` at many places in the code. Any one of them can throw this exception. Its not good practice. Rather use Apache Commons FileUpload.

Comment: can you give me an example of Apache Commons FileUpload, Hardik?

Answer (score 0):

You should have to use Apache [Commons FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/) API to upload a file or you may use *Servlet 3.0* - `Part` API.